# Difflib.SequenceMatcher isjunk optional parameter query: how to ignore whitespaces, tabs, empty lines?

Tags: python, lambda, difflib

I am trying to use Difflib.SequenceMatcher to compute the similarities between two files. These two files are almost identical except that one contains some extra whitespaces, empty lines and other doesn't. I am trying to use

```
s=difflib.SequenceMatcher(isjunk,text1,text2)
ratio =s.ratio()
```

for this purpose.

So, the question is how to write the lambda expression for this isjunk method so the SequenceMatcher method will discount all the whitespaces, empty lines etc. I tried to use the parameter lambda x: x==" ", but the result isn't as great. For two closely similar text, the ratio is very low. This is highly counter intuitive.

For testing purpose, here are the two strings that you can use on testing:

> What Motivates jwovu to do your Job
>   Well? OK, this is an entry trying to
>   win $100 worth of software development
>   books despite the fact that I don‘t
>   read
>
> programming books. In order to win the
>   prize you have to write an entry and
>   what motivatesfggmum to do your job
>   well. Hence this post. First
>   motivation
>
> money. I know, this doesn‘t sound like
>   a great inspiration to many, and
>   saying that money is one of the
>   motivation factors might just blow my
>   chances away.
>
> As if money is a taboo in programming
>   world. I know there are people who
>   can‘t be motivated by money.   Mme, on
>   the other hand, am living in a real
>   world,
>
> with house mortgage to pay, myself to
>   feed and bills to cover. So I can‘t
>   really exclude money from my
>   consideration. If I can get a large
>   sum of money for
>
> doing a good job, then   definitely
>   boost my morale. I won‘t care whether
>   I am using an old workstation, or
>   forced to share rooms or cubicle with
>   other
>
> people, or have to put up with an
>   annoying boss, or whatever. The fact
>   that at the end of the day I will walk
>   off with a large pile of money itself
>   is enough
>
> for me to overcome all the obstacles,
>   put up with all the hard feelings and
>   hurt egos, tolerate a slow computer
>   and even endure

And here's another string

> What Motivates You to do your Job
>   Well? OK, this is an entry trying to
>   win $100 worth of software development
>   books, despite the fact that I don't
>   read programming books. In order to
>   win the prize you have to write an
>   entry and describes what motivates you
>   to do your job well. Hence this post.
>
> First motivation, money. I know, this
>   doesn't sound like a great inspiration
>   to many, and saying that money is one
>   of the motivation factors might just
>   blow my chances away. As if money is a
>   taboo in programming world. I know
>   there are people who can't be
>   motivated by money. Kudos to them. Me,
>   on the other hand, am living in a real
>   world, with house mortgage to pay,
>   myself to feed and bills to cover. So
>   I can't really exclude money from my
>   consideration.
>
> If I can get a large sum of money for
>   doing a good job, then thatwill
>   definitely boost my morale. I won't
>   care whether I am using an old
>   workstation, or forced to share rooms
>   or cubicle with other people, or have
>   to put up with an annoying boss, or
>   whatever. The fact that at the end of
>   the day I will walk off with a large
>   pile of money itself is enough for me
>   to overcome all the obstacles, put up
>   with all the hard feelings and hurt
>   egos, tolerate a slow computer and
>   even endure

I ran the above command, and set the isjunk to lambda x:x==" ", the ratio is only 0.36.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

If you match all whitespaces the similarity is better:

```
difflib.SequenceMatcher(lambda x: x in " \t\n", doc1, doc2).ratio()
```

However, difflib is not ideal to such a problem because these are two nearly identical documents, but typos and such produce differences for difflib where a human wouldn't see many.

Try reading up on [tf-idf](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Tf-idf), [Bayesian probability](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Bayesian_probability), [Vector space Models](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Vector_space_model) and [w-shingling](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/W-shingling)

I have written a an [implementation of tf-idf](http://hg.codeflow.org/tfclassify) applying it to a vector space and using the dot product as a distance measure to classify documents.

Comment: The link to your implementation seems to be broken!

Answer (score 2):

Using your sample strings:

```
>>> s=difflib.SequenceMatcher(lambda x: x == '\n', s1, s2)
>>> s.ratio()
0.94669848846459825
```

Interestingly if ' ' is also included as junk:

```
>>> s=difflib.SequenceMatcher(lambda x: x in ' \n', s1, s2)
>>> s.ratio()
0.7653142402545744
```

Looks like the new lines are having a much greater affect than the spaces.

Answer (score 2):

Given the texts above, the test is indeed as suggested:

```
difflib.SequenceMatcher(lambda x: x in " \t\n", doc1, doc2).ratio()
```

However, to speed up things a little, you can take advantage of CPython's [method-wrappers](http://mail.python.org/pipermail/python-list/2005-April/320354.html):

```
difflib.SequenceMatcher(" \t\n".__contains__, doc1, doc2).ratio()
```

This avoids many python function calls.

Answer (score 1):

I haven't used Difflib.SequenceMatcher, but have you considered pre-processing the files to remove all blank lines and whitespace (perhaps via regular expressions) and then doing the compare?